# The Content-Length header occurred more than once, at most one is allowed

Tags: flutter, dart, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

when i try to connect over the following link:

```
http://192.168.4.1/wifisave?s=asdasd&p=10001010101010&ip=192.168.1.202&gw=192.168.1.1&sn=255.255.255.0&email=new@test.com&pass=123456789&alarm=1
```

I get the following error

> The Content-Length header occurred more than once, at most one is
> allowed.

even though normal link like

```
http://192.168.1.200/anything
```

do works,

even thought it was working before, I don't know if the upgrade of the latest version of the library did affect that, tried to downgrade but I can't due to null-saftey restrictions and other depandancies..
the line of code:

```
try {
String overAllLink='http://192.168.4.1/wifisave?s=asdasd&p=10001010101010&ip=192.168.1.202&gw=192.168.1.1&sn=255.255.255.0&email=new@test.com&pass=123456789&alarm=1';
    response = await http.get(Uri.parse(overAllLink));
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

EDIT: server response when I try to from an API tester is

```
> Host: 192.168.4.1
> User-Agent: insomnia/2021.2.2
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 25

| --X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY--

* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 1210
< Content-Length: 1210 //second one.
< Connection: close
```

so the server appears to send the Content-Length twice, so how can I ignore this or solve it, my server is ESP8266 with WiFiManger .16 library installed.

Comment: It sounds like your HTTP server is incorrectly sending the `Content-Length` header in the HTTP response.

Comment: I tried to connect to the same link via my laptop and also via google chrome on my android and it works!?, what could possibly be the problem please

Comment: Can you inspect the response headers to see what your HTTP server sends you?

Comment: With so many tries i get nothing else than:header was called on null.,

Comment: Any idea how to get to the header response from inside the package maybe

Comment: alright, I updated my question, maybe you can help?

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45679.  I don't think there's anything you can do other than to complain to whoever wrote the HTTP server (but it seems that you've already done that in https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/issues/1235).

Comment: Thanks for making that, I am really grateful for your help. and yeah the issue that you have mentioned has just solved, and it's now working, it was sending the Content-length twice since 2015 by mistake as the owner mentioned, though it was working for me here in a flutter, don't know if any update in flutter SDK version or HTTP package did affect that, you've mentioned something good which is 'accepting multiple identical values should be okay' which is a very good idea to avoid any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the problem was with my ESP8266 server, it was sending the Content-Length twice by mistake as mentioned in the question, opening an issue [here](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/issues/1235) to mention that did solve the problem thanks to the library owner.